# Solving Simple Partial Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, proof-writing, partial-derivative, proof-explanation

I can't solve this partial differential equation.
$$x\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}+ (\alpha+1-x)\phi =0$$

The short answer in the book which i read from it ,
after solving the system $$ \frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{d\phi}{(x-\alpha-1)\phi} $$

is $$ \sigma ( xy^{-1},\frac{e^{x}}{x^{\alpha+1}\phi}) $$

then the author choose the special case 
$$ (xy^{-1})\frac{e^{x}}{x^{\alpha+1}\phi}-1=0 $$

and he obtain finally $$ \phi=x^{-\alpha} y^{-1} e^{x} $$

Please, can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: This is a typical application of the "method of characteristics" used to solve a first order linear PDE. See any course on the subject. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we search one particular solution easy to find, on the form $\Phi_p(x)$ : $$x\frac{d\Phi_p}{dx}+(\alpha+1-x)\Phi_p(x)=0$$ $$\Phi_p(x)\: e^x x^{-\alpha-1}$$ Then we change of function : $\Phi(x,y)= F(x,y)\Phi_p(x)= F(x,y)e^x x^{-\alpha-1}$

$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x} =\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}e^x x^{-\alpha-1}+F(x,y)e^x x^{-\alpha-1}-(\alpha+1)F(x,y)e^x x^{-\alpha-2}$

$\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial y}= \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}e^x x^{-\alpha-1}$

We put $\Phi$ , $\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial y}$ into : $$x\frac{d\Phi}{dx}+y\frac{d\Phi}{dy}+(\alpha+1-x)\Phi=0$$ and simplify : 
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}e^x x^{-\alpha} +y\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}e^x x^{-\alpha-1} =0$$
$$x\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} +y\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} =0$$
This PDE is easy to solve (change $x=e^X$ and $y=e^Y$) 
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial X} +\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y} =0$$
which wellknown general solution is  $F(X,Y)=F(X-Y)$ any derivable function $F$.
$$\Phi(x,y)=e^x x^{-\alpha-1}F(\ln|x|-\ln|y|)=e^x x^{-\alpha-1}f \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)$$
any derivable function $f$

Comment: Last line should be $\ln x - \ln y$, not $e^x-e^y$. Hence, a function of $x/y$, or, if one prefers, a function of the polar angle only (not the radius); this last formulation also allows $x$ and/or $y$ to be negative.

Comment: @ Hans Lundmark : Thanks you very much for pointing out my obvious mistake. This has been corrected.

Comment: See my update .

Comment: @ Hamada Al : I saw your update. What exactly is your problem ? If you are not familar with the "method of characteristics", you cannot follow what the author did. Instead of, solve the PDE with the method shown in my answer. If you want absolutely use the method of characteristics, it is necessary to learn it. If you don't want to find the general solution of the PDE, but only a particular solution, a simple method is the "separation of variables" (see the answer of mvw, but the second to last equation giving $f(x)$ must be corrected).

Answer (score 1):

One of the simple methods is separation of variables which looks for a solution of the form
$$
\phi(x,y) = f(x)\, g(y)
$$
Putting this into the PDE gives
$$
x\, f'(x)\, g(y) + y\, f(x)\, g'(y) + (\alpha + 1 - x)\, f(x)\, g(y) = 0 
$$
Next is assuming $f(x) \ne 0$ and $g(y) \ne 0$ and for these $(x,y)$ sorting the dependencies on $x$ to the left and those on $y$ to the right:
$$
x \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} + (\alpha + 1 - x) 
= -y \frac{g'(y)}{g(y)}
= C = \mbox{const.} 
$$
This gives two ODEs
$$
f'(x) + \frac{\alpha + 1 - x - C}{x} f(x) = 0  \\
g'(y) + \frac{C}{y} g(y) = 0
$$
which have the solutions
$$
f(x) = q\, e^x\, x^{-(\alpha+1)+C} \\
g(y) = r\, y^{-C}
$$
for some integration constants $q$ and $r$.

Update: Found a mistake (forgot to feed the solver with $C$ for the first ODE). Better check the resulting solution $\phi(x,y) = f(x)\, g(y)$ to be sure.

Update: JJacquelin spotted another problem with the ODE for $f$, oh my.

Comment: See my update  .

Comment: @ mvw : there is a mistake in the ODE involving $f(x)$. The correct writting is : $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{C-\alpha-1+x}{x}$$ which leads to:

Comment: @JJacquelin I take it offline to check, thanks for the hint.